# How do I update shared data from a child process?

Tags: c, fork, shared-memory, mmap, memcpy

I'm trying to make a program which forks 5 children. The children all access shared memory to read in a number and increase it by one until the number reaches 100. The children are able to read in the value in the shared memory, but they aren't updating it. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sched.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //create shared memory with children and copy into it the starting number 0
    void* shmem = mmap(NULL, 4, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
    char number[10] = "0";
    memcpy(shmem, number, sizeof(number));

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
            int childPID = fork();

            if(childPID == 0)
            {
                    //read a number in from shared memory
                    int origNum = atoi(shmem);

                    if(origNum < 100)
                    {
                            int newNum = origNum + 1;
                            //cast the new number to a string to be sent to shared memory
                            char newNumString[10];
                            sprintf(newNumString, "%i", origNum);
                            //send the new number to shared memory
                            memcpy(shmem, newNumString, sizeof(newNumString));

                            printf("I'm child %i. PID: %i. PPID: %i. Read in: %i and printed out %i\n", (i + 1), getpid(), getppid(), origNum, newNum);
                            printf("Current value in shmem: %s\n", shmem);

                            //yield process to allow other processes to run
                            sched_yield();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            exit(0);
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                    printf("I'm a parent. PID: %i. Num: %s\n", getpid(), shmem);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: `shmem` is local variable. try make it global. also use `volatile` here is a good idea.

Comment: I tried your suggestions and the result is the same as before.

Comment: you allocate 4 bytes by `mmap` and tried to write 10 bytes... try allocate 10 bytes by `mmap`

Comment: Oops. That was left in from an early version. I fixed it, but still same problem.

Comment: it seems like children does not have enough time to modify the value. try increase number of children to 100000.

Comment: there are only two valid signatures for function: `main()`.   The posted code is using one of them.  When the parameters `argc` and `argv[]` are not used, then should use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: there are three kinds of returned value from `fork()`  1) <0  when an error occurred  2) ==0 when in child process  3) >0 when in parent process.  The posted code is failing to handle the error condition.

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <unistd.h>` for the `fork()` function prototype.

Comment: the posted code is missing the handling of an error return condition from the call to `mmap()`

Comment: since several different processes are accessing the char string that contains the number,  to avoid race conditions, each process should be using a named muted to protect that string while updating that string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the most obvious problem is:

```
sprintf(newNumString, "%i", origNum);
```

which is setting the 'new' string from the 'old' value, so the data in the shared memory is never being updated to the 'new' value.

However, there are several other problems involving 'race' conditions.
Which can be corrected via a mutex with the 'share' attribute.

Note: without the 'shared' attribute, multiple processes accessing the same mutex is undefined behavior.

Caveat: I did not include checking all the returned values from the calls to the system functions, especially those functions handling the mutex setup.  You should add that checking.

Caveat: I did not include code to destroy the mutex.  You should add that statement.

Caveat: I did not include code to release the memory mapped memory.  You should add that statement.

there is the problem of exiting the parent process before the child processes have all exited.  This results in Zombie processes, where the child processes used to be.

there is the 'problem' of using 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

In the following code, I have documented why each header file is being included.  This makes certain activities much easier to accomplish.

I left some of the original code (commented out) to illustrate some of the changes.

I used a 'cast' when needed, to avoid 'implicit conversion' warnings from the compiler ( `gcc` on linux )
The following code corrects the problems, including those listed in the question's comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>     // printf(), perror(), sprintf()
#include <stdlib.h>    // atoi(), exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <sys/mman.h>  // mmap(), MAP_FAILED
#include <string.h>    // strcpy(), memset(), 
#include <sched.h>     // sched_yield()

#include <unistd.h>    // fork(), pid_t, getpid(), getppid()
#include <pthread.h>   // pthread_mutex_lock(),
                       // pthread_mutex_unlock(),
                       // pthread_mutexattr_init(),
                       // pthread_mutex_init(),
                       // pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(),
                       // PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED,
                       // pthread_mutex_t,
                       // pthread_mutexattr_t
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>  // waitpid()

#define MAX_CHILDREN 5
#define MAX_NUM_LEN  10

struct shared
{
    char number[ MAX_NUM_LEN ];
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
};

struct shared *shmem;

//int main (int argc, char* argv[])
int main( void )
{
    //create shared memory with children and copy into it the starting number 0
    if( MAP_FAILED == (shmem = (struct shared*)mmap(NULL, sizeof( struct shared), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0) ) )
    {
        perror( "mmap failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, mmap successful

    //char number[10] = "0";
    memset( shmem, '\0', sizeof( struct shared ) );
    //memcpy(shmem, number, sizeof(number));

    // setup the mutex, include the 'shared' attribute
    pthread_mutexattr_init(&shmem->attr);
    pthread_mutexattr_setpshared( &shmem->attr,  PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED );
    pthread_mutex_init(&shmem->mutex, &shmem->attr );

    //int i;
    pid_t childPID[ MAX_CHILDREN ] = {0};

    for( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
    {
        childPID[i] = fork();

        switch( childPID[i] )
        {
            case -1:
                perror( "fork failed" );
                break;

            case 0:
            {  // then child63

                while( 1 )
                {
                    pthread_mutex_lock( &shmem->mutex );

                    //read a number in from shared memory
                    int origNum = atoi( shmem->number );

                    if( origNum < 100 )
                    {
                        int newNum = origNum + 1;

                        //cast the new number to a string to be sent to shared memory
                        char newNumString[ MAX_NUM_LEN ] = {'\0'};
                        sprintf(newNumString, "%i", newNum);

                        //send the new number to shared memory
                        strcpy( &shmem->number[0], newNumString );

                        printf( "I'm child %i. PID: %i. PPID: %i. Read in: %i and printed out %i\n",
                            (i + 1),
                            getpid(),
                            getppid(),
                            origNum,
                            newNum );

                        printf( "Current value in shmem: %s\n", shmem->number );

                        // allow other processes to access the number in shared memory
                        pthread_mutex_unlock( &shmem->mutex );

                        //yield process to allow other processes to run
                        sched_yield();
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        // allow other processes to access the number in shared memory
                        pthread_mutex_unlock( &shmem->mutex );
                        exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

            default:
                // then parent
                printf("I'm a parent. PID: %i. Num: %s\n", getpid(), (char*)shmem);
                break;
        } // end switch
    } // end for each child

    for( int i=0; i< MAX_CHILDREN; i++ )
    {
        int status;

        if( -1 != childPID[i] )
        { // then child process exists
            waitpid( childPID[i], &status, 0 );
        }
    }
} // end function: main
```

here is an excerpt from the output of the corrected program:

```
I'm a parent. PID: 25961. Num: 
I'm a parent. PID: 25961. Num: 1
I'm child 1. PID: 25962. PPID: 25961. Read in: 0 and printed out 1
I'm a parent. PID: 25961. Num: 1
Current value in shmem: 1
I'm child 2. PID: 25963. PPID: 25961. Read in: 1 and printed out 2
I'm a parent. PID: 25961. Num: 2
Current value in shmem: 2
I'm child 2. PID: 25963. PPID: 25961. Read in: 2 and printed out 3
Current value in shmem: 3
I'm a parent. PID: 25961. Num: 3
I'm child 4. PID: 25965. PPID: 25961. Read in: 3 and printed out 4
Current value in shmem: 4
...
I'm child 4. PID: 25965. PPID: 25961. Read in: 95 and printed out 96
Current value in shmem: 96
I'm child 3. PID: 25964. PPID: 25961. Read in: 96 and printed out 97
Current value in shmem: 97
I'm child 4. PID: 25965. PPID: 25961. Read in: 97 and printed out 98
Current value in shmem: 98
I'm child 3. PID: 25964. PPID: 25961. Read in: 98 and printed out 99
Current value in shmem: 99
I'm child 4. PID: 25965. PPID: 25961. Read in: 99 and printed out 100
Current value in shmem: 100
```